# Compiler define, redirect function to different name

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

When using the edk2 (UEFI), functions like memcpy and memset are not available, but they have functions CopyMem and SetMem. Normally that is not too much of a problem, but sometimes the compiler does optimizations that replace my code with memcpy/memset and I get linker errors saying that I have a unresolved reference to them. As far as I can tell, they are used essentially the same (same args and whatnot).

I was wondering what would be possible to fix this rather than individually dealing with the instances as they happen. I tried googling compiler macros, but I couldn't find a good example to see if it would be a good way to do it.

Comment: Consult your compiler (and linker) documentation. Many linkers can be told to do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler inserts `memcpy()` and `memset()` as a part of the optimization process, then there's **nothing you can achieve using macros.** Your chances are:

I. Reduce the optimization level gradually in each individual case until the linker error goes away.

II. Switch to a conforming standard library

III. Implement `memcpy()` and `memset()` manually.

Comment: my particular problem was "solved" by adding the /Od flag, not that that is really a good solution. I tried /Oi-, but that gave me errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GCC,

You can disable the introduction of `memcpy()` by using the flag `-fno-builtin`.

Using the `__REDIRECT` macro may also work (in `sys/cdefs.h`) :

```
__REDIRECT (memcpy, (void *dest, const void *src, size_t n), CopyMem);
```

Comment: by necessity, im using vs2008

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround create forwarding wrappers:

```
void* memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n) {
    return CopyMem(dest, src, n);
}
```

Comment: "intrinsic function, cannot be defined" :(

Comment: Then your only option is Project Properties >C++ >Optimization >Enable Intrinsic functions >No